# generate pdf on click button in react js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm searching data from db and results displays in table form.Then user can download pdf of any record.
I'm using @react-pdf/renderer library to generate pdf but problem with this library is that its generate pdf of all results once. therefore system hangs due to large number of result.
I need a library which only generate pdf to user specific record not all at once.

below is example

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { PDFDownloadLink, Document, Page,Text } from '@react-pdf/renderer'

const _data = [
    {
      name: 'Bi'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ars'
    },
    {
      name: 'Saee'
    }
]


const MyDoc = ({data}) => (
  <Document>
    <Page>
    <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    </Page>
  </Document>
)

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(_data);
  const clickHandler = (key) => {
    return (
      <PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc  data={data[key]} />} fileName="somename.pdf">
        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : url)}
      </PDFDownloadLink> 
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {data.map((item, i) => {
          return (
              <tr key={i} onClick={() => clickHandler(i)}>
                <td>{i}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
              </tr>   
          );
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
)
  }

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i have tested the code you give to us, and it only fetch the row which corresponds to the key so i think this is as expected, but returning just a PDFDowloadLink doesn't work, because it has to be rendered to allow the user to click it.

So i think your problem is that you want to click on a row, generate a link to download just that specific row instead of generating a link for each one.

You may be able to do that by just adding another state in the App.

For example if you are handling users you can add

```
const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
```

to manage the information about the specific row you want to convert to PDF.

Then use your click listener to modify the user state with the row information and render a link in the DOM managed by a condition (if the user is not null display a link).

for example, if you want to manage that in your App method, it may be something like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(_data);
  const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
  const clickHandler = (key) => {
    setUser(data[key]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {data.map((item, i) => {
          return (
              <tr key={i} onClick={() => clickHandler(i)}>
                <td>{i}</td>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
              </tr>   
          );
        })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      {data.map(value => console.log(value))}
          {user ? (<PDFDownloadLink document={<MyDoc  data={user} />} fileName="somename.pdf">
        {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' :<a href={url}>Url Link here</a>)}
          </PDFDownloadLink>) : null}
    </div>
)
  }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks **Jason** for your valuable answer.
Actually this is not real code. I'll try this in real program and hopefully, this should work there.
Your answer saves a lot of mine work.
Once again Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about that. It has a very simple solution just using npm react to pdf.

**install this in your project**

```
npm install react-to-pdf
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactTOPdf from "react-to-pdf";

const ref = React.createRef();
const PDF = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="background_color" >
        <div className="pdf_container" ref={ref} style={{
          This should be your page what you want to make pdf.
        </div>
        <ReactTOPdf targetRef={ref} >
          {({ toPdf }) => 
            <button onClick={toPdf} className="get_started">
              Download
            </button>
          }
        </ReactTOPdf>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default PDF;
```